Möbius function of distributive lattice only takes values $\pm 1$ and $0$.
In this Wikipedia article, I found the statement

[...] shares some properties with distributive lattices: for example, its Möbius function takes on only values 0, 1, −1.

My question is: How it can be shown that the Möbius function of a locally finite distributive lattice only takes values in $\{-1,0,1\}$?
The property is not true any more for the bigger class of modular lattices. For example, in the $M_3$ lattice (the smallest example of a modular non-distributive lattice), $\mu(0,1) = 2$.
EDIT
The original source appears to be Section 5, Example 1 (p. 349) in Gian-Carlo Rota, On the foundations of combinatorial theory I. Theory of Möbius functions, Zeitschrift für Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie und verwandte Gebiete 2.4 (1964), 340–368, doi: 10.1007/BF00531932.
The proof is based on quite some theory developed before.
I wonder if there is a short direct, self-contained proof of the statement.

My search gave immediately this paper, which answers the question (it has the reference $[11]$). There are many more related papers. Why didn't it show up in your search?

@DietrichBurde Thank you! Actually, I had come across that paper, but I missed the part pointing to [11]. I've edited edited my question accordingly.

I'm not sure if you agree, but I think the following approach is much more accessible and doesn't use all that mathematical apparatus with which I (and perhaps you) am not acquainted. Maybe others will think the opposite.
We start with a lemma which is stated but not proven in [3, page 345]:

Proposition 1. The Möbius function on any segment $[x,y]$ of (a poset) $P$ equals the restriction to $[x,y]$ of the Möbius function of $P$.

Of course this just follows from the fact that the sum considered (if $x\leq y$; otherwise it's $0$ in both cases) has exactly the same summands.
The following is stated, but again not proven, in [1, page 98]:

Theorem 2 (Rota). Let $L$ be a finite lattice.
Then for all $x \in L$,
$$\mu(0,x) = \sum_B(-1)^{|B|}$$
where the sum is over all $B \subseteq A(L)$ such that $\bigvee B = x$ (where $A(L)$ is the set of atoms of $L$).

This result can be proven like Theorem 1.1 in the same paper, or can be seen as a particular case, considering $\trianglelefteq$ to be equality.
(Note that in [1], the Möbius function is unary, but what they refer to as $\mu(x)$ is to be understood as $\mu(0,x)$, when we consider the binary case.)
A consequence of this is the following.

Proposition 3 (Hall).
Let $L$ be a finite lattice where the join of the atoms is (strictly) less than $1$. Then $\mu(0,1)=0$.

This follows from Theorem 2 because under the conditions of this Proposition there is no $B \subseteq A(L)$ such that $\bigvee B = 1$, and so the sum in Theorem 2 is empty (no summand).
Using Proposition 1, we can now state the following generalization of Proposition 3, which is actually an equivalent result.

Corollary 4. Let $L$ be a finite lattice and $x,y \in L$, with $x \leq y$.
If $y$ is not the join of elements covering $x$, then $\mu(x,y)=0$.

Let us consider the Boolean case.

Lemma 5. Let $B$ be a finite Boolean algebra.
Then, for $x,y \in B$, with $x\leq y$, we have
$$\mu(x,y) = (-1)^{h(y)-h(x)},$$
where $h$ is the height function.

To prove it, since a finite Boolean algebra is representable as the powerset of a finite set, it's enough to prove that, for a finite set $X$, in the Boolean algebra of its subsets, if $A \subseteq B$ then
$$\mu(A,B) = (-1)^{|B|-|A|}.$$
Notice also that, by using Proposition 1, we don't loose generality by assuming that $A=\varnothing$, so we'll prove that, for $B \subseteq X$,
$$\mu(\varnothing,B) = (-1)^{|B|}.$$
By induction on $|B|$.
If $|B|=0$, then $B = \varnothing$ and $\mu(\varnothing,\varnothing) = 1 = (-1)^0$.
Suppose the result is valid for sets with cardinal strictly smaller than $|B|$.
By the formula of the Möbius function,
\begin{align}
\mu(\varnothing, B)
&= -\sum_{A \subset B}\mu(\varnothing,A)\\
&= -\sum_{A \subset B}(-1)^{|A|}\\
&= -\sum_{A \subseteq B}(-1)^{|A|} + (-1)^{|B|}.
\end{align}
But, using the binomial formula,
\begin{align}
\sum_{A \subseteq B}(-1)^{|A|}
&= 1 - |B| + \binom{|B|}{2} - \cdots\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{|B|}\binom{|B|}{k}(-1)^k\\
&= (1 + (-1))^{|B|} = 0,
\end{align}
whence $\mu(\varnothing, B) = (-1)^{|B|}$.
A final auxiliary result.

Lemma 6. Let $L$ be a finite distributive lattice and $x,y \in L$ with $x \leq y$.
If $y$ is the join of elements covering $x$, then the interval sub-lattice $[x,y]$ is Boolean.

Since $[x,y]$ is already a bounded distributive lattice, we just have to prove that it's complemented.
So let $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ be the elements covering $x$ which are below $y$ (that is, the atoms of $[x,y]$).
It follows from distributivity that any subset of these atoms has a different join.
So, if $x \leq u \leq y$, and $a_{1_u}, \ldots, a_{k_u}$ are the atoms below $u$, then $u'$ is the join of $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\} \setminus \{a_{1_u}, \ldots, a_{k_u}\}$.
Now for the main result, if $L$ is a finite distributive lattice and $x,y \in L$, then $\mu(x,y) = 1$ if $x=y$; $\mu(x,y) = 0$ if $x \nleq y$, and if $x\leq y$, either the interval sub-lattice $[x,y]$ is Boolean, in which case $\mu(x,y) \in \{-1,1\}$ as it follows from Lemma 5, or it isn't and then by Lemma 6 $y$ is not the join of covers of $x$, whence by Corollary 4 $\mu(x,y) = 0$.
Let me just add that this result, and also Corollary 4 and Lemma 5, are exercises in [2, Ch.IV,§3].

[1] Andreas Blass and Bruce Sagan, Möbius functions of Lattices, Advances in Mathematics 187, 94-123 (1997).
[2] George Grätzer, General Lattice Theory, second edition, Birkhäuser, 2003.
[3] Gian-Carlo Rota, On the foundations of combinatorial theory I: Theory of Möbius functions, Zeit. fur Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie 2, 340-368 (1964).

Many thanks for this thorough answer!! I hope more people will share me upvoting.

Do you happen to have a citation for Lemma 2 (Hall) ? I need exactly this result in a paper which I'm writing, so I'd like to cite the correct source. Thanks!

@DavidESpeyer A possibility would be the paper from Rota, page 349. Now, that paper has a reference to a paper of Hall of which I don't have a copy, and can't access, and I suppose it's the source of the result, which is A contribution to the theory of groups of prime power order, Proc. London Math. Soc. II, 36 (1932) 39-95. Yeah it doesn't seem to be the same topic, but sometimes results come from different areas. That's all I know about it.
